# Connect to a database in cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cpanel

I am using [PTISP](https://ptisp.pt/) (A Portuguese Hosting ISP Company) as a server to store my site but my database isn't working so, my question is: How can I connect to my database in a PHP file using cPanel?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You need to do few steps:

- Log-in to your Cpanel
- Create Database
- Create User / password
- Assign that User to the created database
- Open PHPMyAdmin
- Select database
- Import sql file
- Your PHP file should looks like:

  $dbConn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName); // it will create connection

now you can execute your query like:

```
$query = "select * from tablename;";
$result= $dbConn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object(){
    var_dump($row);//it will print complete row just to show what is in it.
}
```

Comment: I already done the first 7 steps...what do I put in the PHP file (mysqli_connect statement)?

Comment: @GuilhermeR if you want to access it from the browser then you put it in the `/public_html/` folder in your account folder on CPanel. I would **highly recommend** [**READING THE CPANEL DOCUMENTATION**](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/MySQL+Databases)

Comment: @GuilhermeR : I updated the answer w.r.t PHP file to connect database

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Thanks a lot